# utilizando array_push no cakephp 2x

Tags: php, cakephp

Estou tentando adicionar um array que é um retorno de uma consulta do banco de dados, este array nada mais é do que um complemento que quero dentro do meu `$this->request->data['Curso']`, mas o problema é que `array_push` é semelhante a `$array[] = 'value';` então quando debugo meu `$this->request->data['Curso']`, o `array_push` inseriu um `índice 0` onde dentro dele vai todo meu array que passei no array_push, o que devo fazer para não criar este `índice 0` e só adicionar o array direto?
OBS: os campos do array são os índices que precisam estar dentro de `$this->request->data['Curso']`.

```
array_push($this->request->data['Curso'], $escola_infos[0]['EscolaAdicional']);
```

Este é o array do banco de dados:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [EscolaAdicional] => Array
            (
                [fundada_em] => 
                [duracao_aula] => 50
                [porque_estudar_nesta_escola] => - A escola está construída no estilo típico de praia com telhado de palha e jardins onde os estudantes relaxam e desfrutam da natureza.
- +3 salas de aula.
 - Sala de reuniões para estudantes.
 - Cozinha equipada .
- Terraço e Varanda.
- Sala de reuniões para estudantes.
- Cafeteria.
- Calendário semanal de atividades recreativas e tours.
- Acesso livre a Internet - WI FI.
 - Café, chá, leite e água refrigerada.

                       [precisa_saber] => - A escola estará fechada em 2016: Jan 1 / Feb 5 / Mar 16 / Apr 3 / May 1 / Sep 16 / Nov 2 / Nov 16 / Dec 25.
- Quartos Duplos somente para dois estudantes viajando juntos.
 - Serviço de lavanderia não será incluso na acomodação.
 - Transfer e noite extra disponíveis neste campus.
 - Taxa extra para acomodação com banheiro individual (valores a parte/ consultar).
 - Material será emprestado pela escola.

                [deficiente] => 
                [multimidia] => 1
                [laboratorio] => 
                [wifi] => 1
                [biblioteca] => 
                [cozinha] => 1
                [lounge] => 1
                [cafe] => 1
 )

    )

)
```

Tudo que está dentro de `[EscolaAdicional]` eu quero que entre em `$this->request->data['Curso']`
Só que quando uso `array_push` era pra entrar
 `['Curso'] => array(
[fundada_em] => 
[duracao_aula] => 50
more code´...`

só que está entrando assim

```
['Curso'] => array(
[0]=> array(
[fundada_em] => 
[duracao_aula] => 50
more code´...
```

Comment: Olá tem como você postar o modelo de array que vc está obtendo e o que você gostaria que ter?

Comment: atualizei a pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Como o exemplo que você citou, você esta criando um `array` com diversos itens, para chegar no resultado que você quer apenas atribua o valor para a sua váriavel

```
$this->request->data['Curso'] = $escola_infos[0]['EscolaAdicional']
```

---

Uma dica, se você sempre vai pegar apenas 1 valor na variável `$escola_infos`, não faça uma consulta utilizando `all`,  utilize o `first`